# How can I use conditional assignment in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to set the value of `a` equal to the index found unless that index is zero, in which case I want to set it to some number minus that value. I am wondering if it is possible to perform this action (taken from python) in Ruby:

```
a='/-123456789X'.find(y)or 99-x
```

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Not 100% what you want here

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is the most straightforward: `idx = str.index(substr); idx = 99 if idx == 0`. Note that `99` minus zero is `99` and `str.index(substr) #=> nil` if `str` does not contain the substring `substr`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Given `x` and `y`

```
a = "/-123456789X".index(y) || 99 - x
```

Comment: Here's [the docs for String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index). And an important difference between Ruby and Python (and many other languages) is that *0 is not false*. Only `false` and `nil` are false. In Python `0 or 99` is 99. In Ruby `0 || 99` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

In [python](/questions/tagged/python) `string.find(other)` will return the `index` of `other` or `-1` if `other` does not exist in `string`.

In [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) `string.index(other)` will return the `index` of `other` or `nil` if `other` does not exist in `string`.

"Truthy" and "Falsey" values:

- `ruby` acknowledges `nil` as "falsey" and `0` as "truthy"; but
- `python` acknowledges `0` as "falsey" and `-1` as "truthy"

So your current python code has 3 possible return values:

- -1 (non-existent sub-string)
- 99 - x (existent sub-string starting with '/')
- n (index of existent sub-string that does not start with '/')

In order to achieve an equivalent result in ruby your code could look like this:

```
str = '/-123456789X'
a = if y.start_with?('/') && str.index(y)
  99 - x
else
  str.index(y) || -1
end
```

Other alternatives include:

```
# Ruby >= 2.5 using `String#match? 
str.match?(/\A#{y}/) ? 99 - x : str.index(y) || -1
```

That being said your actual request *"I want to set the value of `a` equal to the index found unless that index is zero, in which case I want to set it to some number minus that value"* seems a little different and I am not sure if this means that `x` is "that value" and what `x` should represent in that case.

- Should `x` be the begining index?
- Should `x` be the ending index?